# Import class from shared library in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a shared library repo with this structure:

```
(root)
+- src             
|   +- com
|       +- company
|           +- DeploySteps.groovy
+- vars
|   +- MainDeploySteps.groovy
```

This library importing to job via Jenkinsfile as follows:

```
library identifier: 'jenkinslib@master', retriever: modernSCM(
     [$class       : 'GitSCMSource',
      remote       : 'git@url.to.git:jenkinslib.git',
      credentialsId: 'jenkins-credentials'])
```

Class in repo in src/com/company/DeploySteps.groovy has a method (for example CheckoutSCM) which I want include in Jenkinsfile.

DeploySteps.groovy:

```
def CheckoutSCM() {
    useful steps here
}
```

Is there a possible include this particular method in Jenkinsfile like

```
import com.company.DeploySteps
```

And then use it like:

```
CheckoutSCM('repo-here')
```

In Jenkinsfile later? I read [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) many times but no found answer is there possible import something from `src` folder, not only from `vars`.

Why I am asking because now when import: `import com.company.DeployUtils` and then try invoke method `CheckoutSCM()` see the error in Jenkins console output:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'CheckoutSCM' found
>   among steps

with list of available methods below, where no mine `CheckoutSCM` for sure)

So, is there possible import class from `src` folder to Jenkinsfile?

P.S. I can access in Jenkinsfile MainDeploySteps as

```
MainDeploySteps {}
```

with no problems however.

Comment: I barely remember to use library just as you have written. If you there is some time, you can try to ask some colleague to write some hello world library from scratch and check if it would work (author does not see ist own mistakes). Perhaps you can have a look at this repo for any inspiration https://github.com/wcm-io-devops/jenkins-pipeline-library

Comment: While you can do this, it is awkward, and the reason it is being difficult for you is because this is not normal usage/architecture. Your pipeline typically interfaces with global var methods, which then interface with your library's classes. The method you have listed above seems like a much better fit for a global var method (as it is not a member, nor is it pure Groovy and/or Java), where it would be easier to invoke within your `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard am I understand you correctly that shared library expose ONLY global vars from 'vars' directory, to include that vars to Jenkinsfile? While trying include anything else to Jenkinsfile directly from 'src' folder is not how it was designed, because 'src' classes intended to be include to vars from 'vars' directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wanted to add an answer to address a couple of questions from the OP and the subsequent comments.

> am I understand you correctly that shared library expose ONLY global vars from 'vars' directory, to include that vars to Jenkinsfile? While trying include anything else to Jenkinsfile directly from 'src' folder is not how it was designed, because 'src' classes intended to be include to vars from 'vars' directory.

First let me give some background on shared libraries. There are 2 types referred to as [dynamic shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically) (defined using `library` step) and [global shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#automatic-shared-libraries) (defined in Jenkins global config and accessed using `@Library` annotation). Two important differences between these two are:

- Sandboxing restrictions do not apply to code in global shared library as the code in such libraries is treated as *trusted* (after all, it is configured globally by the administrator). This is not the case for dynamic shared libraries, as these are defined by users and so are not trustable.
- Classes from global shared libraries can be statically referenced in `Jenkinsfile` and get resolved as part of the compilation of `Jenkinsfile`, but this is not possible for dynamic shared libraries as these libraries get defined at runtime and classes can't be cross checked at the time of compilation.

Coming to the OP, it is using the dynamic shared library concept, which means, classes can't be referenced statically. However there are some features put into dynamic shared library that can be taken advantage of. These details can be found in the documentation, but here is a summary:

- `library` step returns a representation of the library that can be assigned to a variable for further use, something like `def myLib = library identifier: ...`
- Classes can be referenced using their fully qualified name on the library object, something like `def myCls = myLib.com.mycom.mypkg.MyClass`
- What you receive is not the actual Groovy class, but a proxy like object that only permits limited operations on the underlying class.
- You can instantiate a new instance using `new` function and it works very similar to the `new` operator. You pass the same arguments that you would pass to a constructor, e.g., `myCls.new(arg1, arg2)`
- You can get a static variable (though you can't set it) or call a static method using the proxy object just like it is the real class. If you are instantiating an object using `new` anyway, then you can access static members through the instance as well (normal Groovy semantics apply).

In both types of libraries, var files are exposed using the same mechanism (referred to also as global vars and custom steps), so there is no difference in usage. Also, the var file executes in the context of the library so with in the var file, you do not need the special syntax to access the classes, whether they are in global or dynamic shared libraries.

Now to answer the real question in the OP, it is possible to call `CheckoutSCM` from the dynamic shared library. If it is defined as a static function, it can be invoked using `myLib.com.company.DeploySteps.CheckoutSCM('repo-here')` and if it is defined as a non-static method, it can be invoked using `myLib.com.company.DeploySteps.new(...).CheckoutSCM('repo-here')`. However in both cases the `DeploySteps` class will not be able to access the steps API so even a simple `echo` will not work. One traditional workaround is to provide the `this` instance of `Jenkinsfile` as a parameter (e.g., `CheckoutSCM(this, 'repo-here')`) which then gets assigned to a `steps` parameter (can be named anything) inside the function. You would then invoke all step calls on the `steps` parameter, e.g., `steps.echo '...'`.